# Why do I have to scroll to refresh my list view?

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to android. I'm trying to get my list view to update, I've tried everything...from calling notifydatasetchanged on the ui thread to just simply recreating my list adapter but for whatever reason when I update, no matter which method I use I have to scroll to see the changes. By this I mean that the data updates (say 13:01 changes to 13:02 in the list), it will update, but to see the change I have to scroll so that 13:01 goes off screen and then move back and it will have updated visually.
Why is this? (I can't post code right now as I'm on my phone but if required I will post later.)

EDIT: Here's the relevant code...sorry it took so long I haven't been at my computer for a couple of days.

Relevant parts of ListFragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MatchAdapter adapter = (MatchAdapter) this.getListAdapter();

    if(futureMatches)
        adapter = new MatchAdapter (this.getActivity(), ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getMatches(), futureMatches);
    else
        adapter = new MatchAdapter (this.getActivity(), ((MainActivity)this.getActivity()).getPastMatches(), futureMatches);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void refresh()
{
    MatchAdapter adapter;

    //Update array in mainactivity
    if(futureMatches)
        MainActivity.refreshMatches((MainActivity) getActivity());
    else
        MainActivity.refreshPastMatches((MainActivity) getActivity());

    //put updated entries in the adapter
    if(futureMatches)
        adapter = new MatchAdapter (getActivity(), ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMatches(), futureMatches);
    else
        adapter = new MatchAdapter (getActivity(), ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getPastMatches(), futureMatches);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    updateList();
}

public void updateList(){

    this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            getListView().refreshDrawableState();
            getListView().invalidate();
        }
    });
}

public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    refresh();
}
```

My adapter class:

```
public class MatchAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private final Activity context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private boolean time = false;
private boolean futureMatchAdapter = true;
private ArrayList<String> matchList;

public MatchAdapter(Context cont, ArrayList<String> matches, boolean isFutureMatchAdapter)
{
    matchList = matches;
    futureMatchAdapter = isFutureMatchAdapter;
    context = (Activity) cont;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount()
{
    return MatchAdapter.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return MatchAdapter.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    String curPos = ""; 
    curPos = MatchAdapter.get(position);

    //times, future matches and past matches are handled differently
    if(curPos.contains("Last updated:"))
        time = true;
    else
        time = false;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if(time)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_item, null);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_time);
        }
        else
        {
            if(futureMatchAdapter)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            }
            else
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.past_feed_item, null);
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title_past);
            }
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    if(futureMatchAdapter)
        holder.title.setText(matchList.get(position));
    else
    {
        String matchString = matchList.get(position);

        String alwaysVisible = matchString.replace("<", "vs");
        alwaysVisible = alwaysVisible.replace(">", "vs");

        if(!time)
            alwaysVisible = alwaysVisible.substring(0, alwaysVisible.length() - 1);

        holder.title.setText(alwaysVisible);

        if(matchString.contains(">"))
        {
            String winner = matchString.substring(0, matchString.indexOf(">")) + "won!";
            alwaysVisible = alwaysVisible.concat(winner);
        }
        else if(matchString.contains("<"))
        {
            String winner = matchString.substring(matchString.indexOf("<") + 2, matchString.indexOf("\n")) + " won!";
            alwaysVisible = alwaysVisible.concat(winner);
        }       

        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new pastMatchesOnclickListener(alwaysVisible) 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                ((TextView) v).setText(matchWinner);
            }
        });
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView title;
    TextView time;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to update your list using the adapter?

```
dataadapter.clear();
dataadapter.addAll(allDataResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

To show and update content in a `ListView` you should:

1. Create or find your `ListView`
2. Create your `ListAdapter`
3. Add your `ListAdapter` to your `ListView`
4. Add data to your `ListAdapter`
5. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ListAdapter`.

Example:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

myListAdapter.add("Hello");
myListAdapter.add("Hi");
myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: if you're using a subclass of `ArrayAdapter` the `notifyDataSetChanged()` will be called for you when you use the methods `add()`, `addAll()`, etc.

Comment: I am doing exactly this, except I'm passing my new data to the adapter and then adding it and calling notifydatasetchanged. I'm using a custom adapter extended from base adapter..could that be something to do with it? edit: oh and I'm using a listfragment

Comment: You should need to add the adapter again. Also, using a `ListFragment` shouldn't make any difference. Maybe you could add your code when you get a chance.